# Find the Taylor series of $f(x) =2^x$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble finding the Taylor series of the function
\begin{equation}
f(x) = 2^x, x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
and showing that it converges to $f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've found that the derivatives of $f(x)$ are $$f'(x)=2^x\ln(2)$$ $$f''(x)=2^x\ln(2)^2$$ and $$f''(x)=2^x\ln(2)^3$$ and I obviously see the pattern with $f^{(n)}(x)=2^x\ln(2)^n$.

I thought about maybe showing it by induction but I'm trouble finding the Taylor series

Comment: $2^x=e^{x\ln 2}.$

Comment: ahh I see. If tried that and I got $e^{xln(2)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(xln(2))^n}{n!}$, does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, but: $$(x\ln 2)^n=x^n\ln^n 2$$

Comment: Okay, so the Taylor series is: $e^{xln(2)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^nln(2)^n}{n!}$

Comment: Usually, we’d write it to make it clear it is a power series: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\ln 2)^n}{n!}x^n$$

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you very much! Do you have any suggestion on how to show that the series converges to $f(x)$?

Comment: @miaa2021 There are alternative forms for the remainder in the Taylor expansion.  If the series converges to $2^x$, then the remainder term goes to $0$ as the number of terms of the expansion goes to infinity.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit, I'm not sure how you determine that it converges towards $2^x$ in the first place.

Comment: The power series for $e^x$ converges everywhere.  In particular, it converges at $x\ln 2$, for all $x$.

Comment: You're asking about the Taylor series, so why not use the definition. In the vicinity of $a$ you know from your classes that $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + f''(a)(x - a)^2/2! + \cdots + R_n(x)$. Evaluate the derivatives to get the general coefficient. Use one of the standard representations of the remainder and bound it as $n \rightarrow \infty$, or use the coefficients and a convergence test to get the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=2^x$, then $f^{(n)}(x)=(\ln 2)^n\cdot 2^x$ and so $f^{(n)}(0)=(\ln2)^n$. Hence, the Taylor series of $f$ about $0$ is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln 2)^n}{n!} \\[5pt]
&= 1+(\ln2)x+\frac{(\ln 2)^2}{2!}x^2+\frac{(\ln 2)^3}{3!}x^3+\ldots
\end{align}
But it is simpler to note that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\ldots
$$
Note that if $x\in\mathbb{R}$,  then $x\ln2\in\mathbb{R}$, and so we can substitute $x\ln 2$ for $t$:
$$
e^{x\ln2}=1+(\ln2)x+\frac{(\ln 2)^2}{2!}x^2+\frac{(\ln 2)^3}{3!}x^3+\ldots
$$
But since $2^x=e^{x\ln 2}$, we get that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
2^x=1+(\ln2)x+\frac{(\ln 2)^2}{2!}x^2+\frac{(\ln 2)^3}{3!}x^3+\ldots
$$
The second approach is preferable because not only does it tell us the Taylor series of $2^x$, it also tells us that $2^x$ is equal to its Taylor series for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Not every function is equal to its Taylor series. For example, consider the Taylor series of the following function about $0$:
$$
\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2} &\text{ if $x\neq0$} \\
0 &\text{ if $x=0$} \, .
\end{cases}
$$